# MATLAB Error: "Vectors must be the same length"

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm getting an error that says "Vectors must be the same length" but I'm not sure why. I'm basically trying to graph a piecewise function with respect to time. I was running into some other issues with the "piecewise" operator earlier, so I decided to use an if statement instead.

```
figure(1);        

t = linspace(0, 30, 200); 

v_wind1 = linspace(0, 20, 100);      
v_wind2 = linspace(20, 0, 100);   

if (0 <= t < 15)                         
    v_wind = v_wind1;                        
elseif (15 <= t <30)                        
    v_wind = v_wind2;                     
end        

plot(t, v_wind);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate `v_wind1` and `v_wind2`.

```
figure(1);        

t = linspace(0, 30, 200); 

v_wind1 = linspace(0, 20, 100);      
v_wind2 = linspace(20, 0, 100);   

v_wind = [v_wind1 v_wind2];    

plot(t, v_wind);
```

This should do the trick!? You want that result, don't you?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Simply use: indexing

```
t = linspace(0, 30, 200); 

v_wind1 = linspace(0, 20, 200);      
v_wind2 = linspace(20, 0, 200);   

v_wind = zeros(size(t)) ;
idx = t >= 0 & t<15 ;
v_wind(idx) = v_wind1(idx) ; 

idx = t >=15 & t < 30 ;
v_wind(idx) = v_wind2(idx) ; 

plot(t,v_wind)
```

Comment: Your answer is badly wrong from my point of view. Since `if (0 <= t < 15)` always evaluates to `1`, the assignment `v_wind = v_wind1;` will be always used - as this is the original problem in the question. You just "fixed" the length of `v_windx`.

Comment: I take the user as noob to MATLAB. If he joins both the vectors, it might not be a generalized code.

Comment: Your code - after your edit - is still wrong in my opinion since the maximum value in `v_wind` is `10` and not `20`, which I think is the requested result.

Comment: I agree with @HansHirse's comment, this still gives the wrong answer, i.e. 10 at t=15 instead of 20.

Comment: I am not considering the what is wrong or right answer......my point is to code a problem with MATLAB syntax, so that the user can extend to his data. As ofnow user has two equal different values....what if he has a single array and he wants to get the values obeying certain condition. First the question itself is not generalized.

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula Then I'm afraid you have completely missed the plot (pun intended :-)). You can produce perfectly syntactically correct MATLAB code, if it doesn't give the right answer, it's still wrong. The code not only needs to be correct from a syntax point of view, but but also produce the correct result, otherwise it's completely pointless pointless and even harmful as it induces people in error.

Comment: You should note that the user is a beginner.......he missed the very simple thing. So I expect he will extend his code further, so I gave that code.